# how to exclude first and last row if group it on particular id

Tags: mysql

I have sample table with data like this

```
id uniqueid values
1   6          0
2   6          1
3   6          2
4   6          0
5   6          1
```

I want result like this

```
id uniqueid values
2   6          1
3   6          2
4   6          0
```

I tried like this

```
select id,uniqueid,values
FROM t1
WHERE 
 id not in(SELECT concat(MAX(message_id_pk),',',min(message_id_pk)) FROM t1
  where uniqueid=6)
  and `uniqueid`=6
 GROUP BY uniqueid
```

but its not working

Comment: Not working how exactly? Error? What is the filter criteria you want to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the desired results by doing self join, Inner query will get the the max and min ids for per group and outer query will filter out the results by using `minid` and `maxid`

```
select a.*
from demo a
join (
  select `uniqueid`,min(id) minid, max(id) maxid
  from demo
  where uniqueid=6
  group by `uniqueid`
) b using(`uniqueid`)
where a.id > b.minid and a.id < b.maxid /* a.id <> b.minid and a.id <> b.maxid  */
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe079/2)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do it by using 2 sub-queries with **`EXISTS`** to exclude the min and max id of each `uniqueid`.

**Query**

```
select `id`, `uniqueid`, `values`
from `your_table_name` t1
    where exists (
    select 1 from `your_table_name` t2
    where t2.`uniqueid` = t1.`uniqueid`
    and t2.`id` > t1.`id`
)
and exists(
    select 1 from `your_table_name` t2
    where t2.`uniqueid` = t1.`uniqueid`
    and t2.`id` < t1.`id`
);
```

**[`Here`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad3853/1)** is a sql fiddle demo

Answer (score -1):

Try this -

```
SELECT id, uniqueid, values
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE id NOT IN (MIN(id), MAX(id));
```